run script after load more button is clicked
I am using the Smash Balloon custom facebook feed pro plugin on wordpress. I have written a php script the alters the $content on the page with the facebook feed so that it changes the links in the posts to buttons and removes some unwanted words etc. The problem I am facing is that my script works great for the posts that are loaded already however when the "load more button" is clicked via the newly loaded posts are not affected by the script I wrote because they were not part of the original page $content that was loaded. Is there a way to trigger my script again when a user clicks the load more button? I also noticed that I had to set the priority of my action to 995 for it to actually change the $content. my website is [https://nicolesfunfinds.com][1] Thanks
My Code:
<?php
function find_class_content($content){  
    global $post;
    if( $post->ID == 63){
        $content = preg_replace ('{<a.*?href="([^"]*)".*?>(.*?\b)<\/a>}i', '<a target="_blank" href="$1" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0 transition-3d-hover btn-width display-buy-now" style="width:250px !important">Buy Now</a>', $content); 
        return $content;
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'find_class_content',995);
?>

Link to cff-scripts.js file where the load more function is fired [https://hosekdentistry.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-facebook-feed-pro/assets/js/cff-scripts.js][1]

How exactly is your script triggered in the first place?

Thank you. I am using the wp plugin code snippets which runs it through the wp-functions I believe. So it is running all the time however when the page loads more of the feed the $content filter had already been applied so it doesn't see the new posts

This seems like it would be better done in JS possibly. You could listen to DOM changes there, too

Otherwise, if I were to guess because I don't use that plugin, that specific $post->ID value isn't tripping on the "load more".
